# How to mark some files not browsable in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

In my AngularJS ASP.NET MVC Web API application I have some HTML templates which look like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
                <input class="col-sm-6 form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" ng-model="accountModelStep2.FirstName" placeholder="first name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...And so on...
    ...Rest of the html omitted. 
</form>
```

The problem is when I launch the application, and browse to say:

```
http://localhost:12405/Templates/RegisterStep2.html
```

IIS actually sends the template as HTML and it's rendered in the browser:

[image]

I don't want these files to be directly browsable, that is even when user keys in such a URL, the browser should either redirect to home page or at least show some error that they are not supposed to ask for such files directly. But when user browses like:

`http://localhost:12405/account/register/step1`

it should be rendered.

How can I do that?

In visual studio solution the files look like this:

[image: HtmlTemplatesOnVisualStudio]

Answer (score 3):

In IIS, on your WebSite, go to `Request Filtering`.

Then select the `Hidden Segments` tab.

And finally: `Add Hidden Segment...` specify the folder you want to hide.

**IIS Request Filterning - Hidden Segments:**

[image: IIS Request Filterning - Hidden Segments]

To allow requests from ajax calls, in the Request Filtering, `URL` tab, `Allow URL...` specify the URL to allow:

[image]

Or directly in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
                <add segment="Templates" />
            </hiddenSegments>
            <alwaysAllowedUrls>
                <add url="/Templates" />
            </alwaysAllowedUrls>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in IIS Express?

Comment: Please see my update. You can set your hidden segments directly in your web.config. Then, your hidden segments will not be browsable if you're debugging with IIS Expess.

Comment: Problem, when I browse to http://localhost:12405/account/register/step1, then the html templates are not rendered.  I want them to be rendered when angularjs wants. How can this be done?

Comment: Try my last update: adding an allowed URL should work for ajax calls but directory browsing should be still blocked with the hidden segments instruction.